# Error encountered resolving symbol values statically with only my own modules

Tags: typescript, angular-cli

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function '`DataModule`', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol `DataModuleRoot` in `E:/shopify-client/src/app/app.module.ts`, resolving symbol `AppModule` in `E:/shopify-client/src/app/app.module.ts`, resolving symbol `AppModule` in `E:/shopify-client/src/app/app.module.ts`

I keep getting this error when building my project with Angular CLI. The frustrating thing is that it only comes up once each time I start `ng serve`, then it doesn't error on subsequent updates. But this often means I cannot just run the build command because the first run results in an error preventing file output. DataModule is a module I made and I used the Angular documentation to make the forRoot method.

```
export function DataModuleRoot(){
  return DataModule.forRoot({});
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    NavtreeComponent,
    JsonifyPipe,
    DebugPipe,
    PanelsComponent,
    IsolateScrollDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpModule,
    DataModuleRoot(),
    PagesModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And here is DataModule

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [DataService]
})
export class DataModule {
  constructor( @Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: DataModule) {
    if (parentModule) {
      throw new Error(
        'DataModule is already loaded. Import it in the AppModule only');
    }
  }

  static forRoot( config: any = {}): ModuleWithProviders {
    const io: Function = function () { };
    const host = (window as any).devHost || config.host || location.origin
    const socket: Socket = false ? io(host) : {
      id: '',
      on: function () { },
      off: function () { },
      emit: function () { },
      isFailed: false
    };

    //;
    (window as any).socket = socket;
    return {
      ngModule: DataModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: DataServiceConfig,
          useValue: {
            socket: socket,
            host: host,
            globalCache: {},
            globalSettings: {},
          }
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

I have read through many other questions like this on StackOverflow, and none of them answer my question.

- I am not using any external library. This is a module I wrote myself using the Angular IO documentation.
- I am not using a factory.

Comment: Does it work when you put `DataModule.forRoot()` inline?

Comment: No, it is the same error. What I don't understand​ is that this is an actual object that is in the array, not a function call. forRoot() returns an object.

Comment: The problem is typical for AoT compilation where functions have to be public/export/non-lambda. I'm thinking the issue lies with your `providers` in the return function of `forRoot`. Either you'd need a token for useValue or there is some value hidden that it doesn't like.

Comment: @Raven, is there a way to have it pack everything up without AoT compiling?

Comment: Well.. you can choose to run the application using the JiT compiler instead of the AoT compiler. It is much more efficient using AoT for production grade apps and taking it into account early on is a good habit. I don't know how your compiler works but if you are interested you should look if there's an option to use JiT instead of AoT

Comment: Ok, is webpack an AoT compiler? I mean, I wish I could just pack all my files without compiling them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole problem was literally that I had the const declarations in the same function. As you can see I can use variables or function calls in the return value, I just can't declare anything in the function body. It's a weakness of the AoT compiler.

```
public static forRoot(config: any = {}): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
        ngModule: DataModule,
        providers: [
            {
                provide: DataServiceConfig,
                useValue: {
                    socket: io('http://localhost'),
                    globalCache: {},
                    globalSettings: {},
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```